# How do I fetch comments with Laravel Pagination that are not redundant?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

**My main problem:**

If user writes a comment and ***then*** decides to load more comments, he will get to see at least **one redundant comment**.

**Causation:**

Via Laravel Pagination the script loads via Axios the last 10 items. After adding one comment and fetching again the next 10 items, the "order" is shifted of one element. Thus, getting one repeated element.

---

**Tries to fix it:**

***First Try:*** 
I tried with Array.prototype.includes() or Lodash Includes:

```
 data(){
    return { items: [] };
 }
 ...
 addWithoutRedudancy(newItems){
    for(let item of newItems){
        if( ! _.includes( this.items, item ) ) this.items.push(item);
    }
 }
```

**Occurring problems:**

1. Even though I seemingly have two of the same objects, I get in my console false if I check:

   ```
   $vm0.items[10] == $vm0.items[11] //False even though objects look the same, and actually are (looking to all properties)
   ```

   That is a huge problem, because Includes can't find the redundant Object! I've no clue why these objects are saved differently. Perhaps because I fetch them over axios on two different timings?
2. But even if it would work, after the user wrote for example 8 new comments, he would get only 2 new comments from the pagination (controller) back, but should get of course the next 10 comments.

***Second Try***

```
/**
 * Fetch all relevant comments.
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @param Selllink $selllink
 */
public function index($username, $selllink)
{
    //Route::prefix('/{username}/{selllink}
    //Sellink gets the model of sell and loads all comments to that sell.
    //get me the latest first (we want to see the current comments)
    //take only 10 coments with paginatation

    return $selllink->sell->comments()
                ->latest()
                ->offset($addedCommentsNumber??) //that can't work...
                ->paginate(10);
}
```

**Occurring problems:** 
   I cannot really offset the whole table. I need to offset the paginated ones and add the missing ones again.

---

**Conclusion**

There must be a much better way to do this. But I just don't know how.

---

**More details explanation (if needed):**

I have a **Vue Comment Component** that fetches the data from my **CommentController** with Pagination:

```
methods: {
        fetch(){
            axios.get(this.url()).then(this.refresh);
        },
        url() {
            this.page++;
            return `${location.pathname}/comments?page=${this.page}`;
        },
        refresh({data}){
            this.dataSet = data;
            this.addWithoutRedudancy(data.data);
        },
}
```

If the users want to get **more** Comments, they just click on the "load more" button and I'm getting the comments loaded

Comment: You could store the id or created_at timestamp of the last loaded comment, then modify your query to only retrieve comments that are before that one?  Not sure what you want to happen with newer comments, though.

Comment: Not really a solution maybe, but you could filter duplicates and not display them twice (in your JS code). The user most likely won't notice it has only loaded 9 items the second time. Obviously this won't work if the user creates 10 comments at once...

Comment: @James Sorry that I answer only now. I had so much to do. I maybe like the idea! I'll give this a try!

Comment: @Namoshek Yeah if James idea doesn't work out I just will load every comment at once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thanks to @James. I'm saving the last ID of all fetched Comments + using a WHERE Query

I changed the Vue Method to:

```
url() {
    this.page++;
    return `${location.pathname}/comments?page=${this.page}&lastComment=${this.idOfLastComment}`;
},
```

And in my Controller:

```
/**
 * Fetch all relevant comments.
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @param Selllink $selllink
 */
public function index($username, $selllink)
{
    $commentID = request('lastComment', $default = 0);
    $filter = $commentID == 0 ? '>' : '<=';

    return $selllink->sell->comments()
                ->where('id', $filter, $commentID)
                ->latest()
                ->paginate(10);
}
```

Works perfectly :)